# Achieving mixture of ~p and ~w formatting with io_lib:format

Tags: erlang

Say I have an arbitrary format string and som corresponding data, and data contains tuples with string elements. As a (shortened) example:

```
Format = "~p~n",
Data = {"ABC"},
```

For a specific purpose, I want to print the same output, but only on a single line. I want to achieve the same formatting as "~p" (ie. `Data` should be printed as `{"ABC"}` not `{[65,66,67]}`. Is this possible?

I guess I could do it in three steps:

- `io_lib:format` with `~p`
- loop through resulting string and remove all new line chars
- regex replace all sequences of multiple consecutive spaces with a single space

But this approach seems tedious and inefficient. Is there some better way to use OTP functions to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the output will never be wider than, say, one million characters, you can specify the output width for the `~p` specifier:

```
io:format("~1000000p", [Data]).
```

Answer (score 3):

As legoscia indicates,`io:format/2` tries to be polite in terms of pretty printing elements and line lengths and whatnot which you can adjust per element via format string parameters. Note that this means the format itself is where you would be controlling the length of output *per element* if you use format control sequences.

An alternative that allows you to declare the total length of the lines (as opposed to each element) is [`io_lib:print/4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#print-4). I tend to find this particular function more useful for things like log message formatting:

```
1> T = {"Some really long things","are in this tuple","but it won't really matter","because they will be in line"}.
{"Some really long things","are in this tuple",
 "but it won't really matter","because they will be in line"}
2> io:format("~tp~n", [T]).
{"Some really long things","are in this tuple","but it won't really matter",
 "because they will be in line"}
3> S = io_lib:print(T, 1, 1000, -1).
[123,
 ["\"Some really long things\"",44,"\"are in this tuple\"",
  44,"\"but it won't really matter\"",44,
  "\"because they will be in line\""],
 125]
4> lists:flatten(S).
"{\"Some really long things\",\"are in this tuple\",\"but it won't really matter\",\"because they will be in line\"}"
5> io:format("~ts~n", [S]).
{"Some really long things","are in this tuple","but it won't really matter","because they will be in line"}
ok
```

Read the documentation for [io](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html) and [io_lib](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html) carefully. There is actually quite a lot of functionality packed in there that pops up from time to time.

Keep in mind that you can also do quite a lot of interesting work by printing individual characters and using ASCII control sequences if the goal is to control the terminal itself. Character-by-character or per-blit screen update string output using [`io:put_chars/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#put_chars-1) can be a powerful tool if the problem you are solving is to build a text-based interface or something similar.